# How to clean dust and spider webs in my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I bought Breezehome and am very happy with it: it is a nice and cozy house with everything I need.

However, I couldn't miss noticing dust spots and spider webs in several places. In dungeons it's acceptable, but in my own house? I sought some way to clean my house.

First I tried to use Unrelenting Force to blow the dust and spider webs away - no luck.

Maybe some fire will burn it and leave the floor/wall clean? No - it just made it worse.

Finally a great idea hit me - broom! I found one, took it and was very disappointed to find I can't equip or use it in any way - also tried just dropping it on the spider webs but of course, that did not help.

Am I doomed to live in a dirty house?

Comment: I have to applaud your creative efforts to get rid of it :)

Comment: Eh, I have my XBox sitting next to some cobwebs right now. Do I care?  Nah.  I simply won't have my skyrim home lookin a mess!

Comment: @desaivv It caused lots of mess, but having such a dirty place I didn't really care.. :)

Comment: I'd try a fire spell... and then buy a new house :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe the cobwebs will be removed when you buy the decorations for your house.

Answer (score 0):

Tricks for removing spiderwebs/cobwebs in Skyrim!

Firstly, yes, it will remove them if you buy the decorations. I tried those at first but you can't remove the light from the candles on the plates even if you remove the candles, which looks weird. So I set out to remove every one of those crummy little webs (and random crates) manually [using the console] so that I could decorate my Breezehome. [using the console]

In case you don't know how to use the console... **SAVE YOUR GAME FIRST!!!** You open it by pressing the tilde, which is the key to the left of the 1 on your keyboard. It looks like this: ~ Then you use the mouse to click on the object you want to delete. A code will appear in the middle of the screen. Then in the console you type "markfordelete" and press enter. Then click the object to deselect it, then click it again. Now it should have this at the end of the code: [D]. Then with it still selected type "disable" and press enter. Press the tilde again to get out of the console. Then save your game and reload it. The object you selected should be gone. (You don't always have to reload to see the change...) If you accidentally deleted a wall or something then you can go back to your previous save. You did save first, as I instructed, right?

Now on to the webs specifically. **The trickiest webs to remove are the ones hanging from the ceiling; the ones that sort of sway. What you have to do is get your face right up in the web so that it pretty much takes up your entire field of vision. This way you are less likely to click the wall or ceiling, though there is still a lot of trial and error.** But most of the web codes (at least in my game) had similar ending numbers, usually eeb, eef, ee-whatever: you get the point. So if you click the wall and ceiling around the web to see their codes, then get right up on the web and start clicking you will be able to tell when you get a number that isn't the wall or ceiling. **For some of the webs I had to climb up on the random crates to reach them. For one of them I had to spawn in a chair to stand on so that I could get right up on it, which I then deleted after I got the web. If you can't get it from one side, move to the other side and try again.** Using this method I managed to clear every web in the Breezehome, though it did take a while. I recommend saving between each web just in case you delete a wall or ceiling in the process and have to return to the previous save.

The absolute hardest one was the one when you first enter the breezehome and turn back to face the door. It is the one on the right. To get it I had to get all the way up against the wall beneath it, turn around and look straight up. I had to click it from the side closest to the wall, which wasn't easy. This one took as much time as all the rest combined! But in the end I was triumphant. (Happy Dance)

To spawn in a chair... get directly under the web you want to remove and look straight ahead. Then enter the console and type: "player.placeatme 0002ec1c" then hit enter and exit the console. Your chair should be there. And, of course you can spawn any item this way as long as you have the right code, which, by the way, is not the code you see when you click on an item using the console. You have to download FNVedit to look up the proper code using that code. I have yet to try FNVedit, so that's all I can tell you about it.

I wish you luck and a speedy de-webbing. I hope this helps at least one person.

Answer (score -4):

Just make your child do chores; it makes them remove cobwebs.

Comment: Not a real answer, I believe, but nice joke!

Comment: No children in this game, unless you mean a follower e.g. Lydia?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There are children in Skyrim, but for the player to be the parent requires DLC.  As for if they can remove cobwebs, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Batophobia oh, never bothered much with DLC's. If the OP will explain in more details it might be a fair answer though.